# What in my ALLOCATE is causing my integer overflow?

Tags: fortran, allocation, gfortran, integer-overflow

I have a set of code in which I declare the size of all my variables. However, I want to change them so some of the variables are allocatable.

This is (what I believe) to be the relevant code of the original.

```
parameter (m=10**5,nchar=2000,ncols=110)
character (LEN=*), PARAMETER :: FORM = "(A)"
character(LEN=nchar),DIMENSION(m) :: data

* determine the length of the data
nlines = 0
do i = 1,m
   read(12,*,end=10)
   nlines = nlines+1
end do
nlines = nlines+1

* read in the data
10  REWIND(unit = 12)
do i = 1,nlines
   read(12,FORM) data(i)
end do
```

This is the form I would like.

```
parameter (m=10**5,nchar=2000,ncols=110)
character (LEN=*), PARAMETER :: FORM = "(A)"
character(LEN=:),DIMENSION(:),allocatable :: data
integer j
character(LEN=100000) :: temp

* determine the length of the data
nlines = 0
j = 0
do while (ios == 0)
   read(12,FORM,end=10,iostat=ios) temp
   if (LEN(TRIM(temp)) .gt. j) THEN
      j = LEN(TRIM(temp))
   end if
   nlines = nlines+1
end do
nlines = nlines+1

10  REWIND(unit = 12)
ALLOCATE (character(LEN=j) :: data(nlines))

* read in the data
do i = 1,nlines
   read(12,FORM) data(i)
end do
```

Problematically, this causes an integer overflow error. "Fortran runtime error: Integer overflow when calculating the amount of memory to allocate". I find this very perplexing as the 'nlines' and 'j' values I obtain from my test dataset are only 10 and 110 respectively.

I have found that if I don't allocate the character length (i.e. keep it a constant), this works.

I am using gfortran, version 4.8.0.

What is wrong with my code/method?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that in the original post. It links to a Rewind command just before the text file is read into 'data'. I'll correct the original post.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.